# Tool for monitoring Hibernate cache usage

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, caching, monitoring

Is there any tool which would allow for monitoring Hibernate 2nd level cache usage? I know that I could use Hibernate API for retrieving such information. But what should I do when I have application which doesn't read the information itself, and I can't modify it? Is there any way to read cache statistics from the outside of the application?

Comment: What container is your application running in?

Answer (score 7):

Quoting Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html_single/#configuration-optional-statistics):

> #### 3.4.6. Hibernate statistics
>
> If you enable
>   `hibernate.generate_statistics`,
>   Hibernate exposes a number of metrics
>   that are useful when tuning a running
>   system via
>   `SessionFactory.getStatistics()`.
>   Hibernate can even be configured to
>   expose these statistics via JMX. Read
>   the Javadoc of the interfaces in
>   `org.hibernate.stats` for more
>   information.

You'll find the `org.hibernate.stats` package-summary [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/stat/package-summary.html).

For the JMX part, have a look at [Publishing statistics through JMX](https://www.hibernate.org/216.html).

For more advanced stuff, you'll have to rely on specific features from your cache provider.

Comment: @Ondra Thanks, link updated (why the hell did JBoss not implement some permanent redirect to the new location, there are so many links on the net pointing to nowhere now, this goes against all best practices...).

Comment: Well, JBoss.org has underwent big structural changes, and unfortunatelly, link preservation was not the priority to be kept in mind when there's only few people taking care of the whole web...

Comment: I wanted to send a redirection request to JBoss.org team, but I don't know the original link :) Do you still have it, accidentally?

Comment: @Ondra The original link was https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/stat/package-summary.html. Ideally, a redirect should be done for both the javadoc and the reference guide, something like https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/ --> http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/

Answer (score 3):

If your 2nd level cache is an EhCache, then you can read cache status from its MBean.

See 'JMX Management and Monitoring' in the ehcache documentation: http://ehcache.org/documentation/jmx.html

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool for monitoring hibernate's cache that has been exposed through JMX. Its called hibernate-jconsole and can be downloaded here - http://hibernate-jcons.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Implement

http://narcanti.keyboardsamurais.de/hibernate-statistics-jsp-reloaded.html

for "human" use