# Hibernate Monitoring Solution

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence, monitoring

I would like to monitor hibernate action.
I see on the internet the zentracker monitor solution that permit to monitor a lot of activity of hibernate.

But It is compatible with the last version of hibernate 3.5.*?

if it's not, do you have solution to monitor query execution time, sessionFactory opened, persitence object created, ... ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Florent

P.S: I'm french, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I see on the internet the zentracker monitor solution that permit to monitor a lot of activity of hibernate. But It is compatible with the last version of hibernate 3.5.x?

Why don't you get the sources and recompile the project with a more recent version of Hibernate Core? Well, I did because I was curious and it doesn't compile, there are a few API changes that require some modifications. But nothing overcomplicated though. And since the project doesn't seem to be very active, your best option would be to make them yourself.

> If it's not, do you have solution to monitor query execution time, sessionFactory opened, persitence object created, ... ?

Well, as I said, you can make it compatible...

I personally gather [Statistics](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-monitoring) via JMX and use a custom tool. From the documentation:

> #### [20.6.2. Metrics](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-monitoring-metrics)
>
> Hibernate provides a number of
>   metrics, from basic information to
>   more specialized information that is
>   only relevant in certain scenarios.
>   All available counters are described
>   in the Statistics interface API, in
>   three categories:
>
> - Metrics related to the general Session usage, such as number of open
>     sessions, retrieved JDBC connections,
>     etc.
> - Metrics related to the entities, collections, queries, and caches as a
>     whole (aka global metrics).
> - Detailed metrics related to a particular entity, collection, query
>     or cache region.
>
> For example, you can check the cache
>   hit, miss, and put ratio of entities,
>   collections and queries, and the
>   average time a query needs. Be aware
>   that the number of milliseconds is
>   subject to approximation in Java.
>   Hibernate is tied to the JVM precision
>   and on some platforms this might only
>   be accurate to 10 seconds.

Have a look at [Performance Monitoring using Hibernate](http://josephmarques.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/performance-monitoring-using-hibernate/) for more inspiration.

#### See also

- [Hibernate Profiler](http://hibernateprofiler.com/): a commercial tool

#### Related questions

- [Tool for monitoring Hibernate cache usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839299/tool-for-monitoring-hibernate-cache-usage)

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [20.6. Monitoring performance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-monitoring)

Comment: Like always, thank you for your help. You are very helpful.
I have successful make hibernate motinoring operate.

Comment: @Delildor @org.life.java Glad you found this helpful.